# Looking for an affordable high density storage solution for my individual bricks

Tags: storage, organisation

As my collection of bricks is growing, my storage space is limited and I'm increasingly interested in doing my own MOCs, I'm looking for a high density storage solution to keep my individual pieces organized efficiently without spending a fortune on it.

The most interesting solution I've found so far is the [PapiMax storage box set](https://www.papimax.co.uk/collections/lego-brick-storage/products/lego-storage-ideas). However, the price of £85.96 (about €95 or $140) just seems way too steep IMO for only 8 boxes.

Can anyone here recommend a storage system that is similar to the PapiMax storage box set in terms of efficiency but more affordable?

Note that I live in Belgium, so a storage system only sold in the US is probably not going to be an option, considering the huge shipping & import costs that go with shipping from the US to Europe.

Answer (score 7):

Very specific to your region (and mine):

The ALDI chain carries the following hobby sorting drawers from time to time (about once a year):

[image: Aldi kleinteile magasin]

They are very cheap, about 7 Euro for each type and they are VERY popular with AFOLs in Belgium and the Netherlands. Unfortunately it is hard to predict when ALDI offers these and they are often sold out immediately.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. It does look very suitable for small pieces, and I don't think a better price is possible. Too bad it's not only available so rarely :-(

Answer (score 6):

Try "Iris storage drawer" on amazon.co.uk. They sell transparent drawers and boxes in several sizes. These (3 large drawers or 6 small drawers) cost about 30 pounds. They are similar to the system that [Jangbricks in his LEGO parts tour](https://youtu.be/T0YrJ2h3W0) is showing.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Thanks for the tip. Someone at Reddit proposed the same storage system, and I found their 8-drawer system [@ Blokker for 28.99 Euro](https://www.blokker.be/nl/p/iris-organizer-chest-8-lades-a4/1388816)... which definitely is affordable. I am a bit worried the trays are a bit big for small pieces, though...

Comment: @JohnSlegers i use these style drawers and plastic food storage boxes inside them for smaller parts - allows you to take out just the brick type you need, and as you can get many different sizes of box it makes the space very customisable based on quantity and size of brick being stored.

Answer (score 2):

In [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BkXTFNWqhJU) video, I made some boxes out of paper, which is a very cheap way. You can make them smaller or bigger when you want. They are not as stable as plastic boxes, but if you reinforce the bottom with cardboard, they are pretty stable. In [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QT03wHwmkcE) video, you can see my DIY shelf, made from plywood and some bars. In my country you can buy plywood and the seller cuts it if you want. The only thing I made by myself is cutting the 24mm x 48mm bar into 72mm long pieces and glued everything together.

Answer (score 0):

You could also go to AVA and use cheap food containers - the [500ml and 1L microwave ones](https://www.ava.be/fr/product/search?keyword=183) are quite popular. Nice for parts you don't use too often; but manipulating stacks of those can be cumbersome at times so you may want to build a frame in which to insert them, in which case they can work as makeshift drawers (for these you don't need to buy lids). Not ideal, but could be cheaper and it might be nice to have the same containers for parts you use often and those which are stashed away

Answer (score 0):

Here, my mom found this useful when I had Lego bricks:

[image]